Is a safety pressure relieve valve combined with a PLC controlled pressure valve enough to achieve performance level D according to ISO 13849?
I use the ISO 13849 standard and ISO 12100 for a safety analysis and risk reduction of a machine.
The simplified description of the machine is a vessel with water and a heater. The vessel is closed. The pressure can get higher if the electric heater heats the water. The pressure is measured with a pressure sensor. When the pressure is too high a PLC opens an electric valve to release the pressure.
If the channel: pressure sensor, PLC, electric-valve fails I need a safety feature. I can find a lot of safety pressure relieve vales when I search the internet these valves confirm to ISO 4126-1 and use a spring to open at a maximum pressure level.
I think I need performance level D for the pressure control safety function. I can calculate the performance level for the electric part but I am lost when I need to add the non electrical safety pressure relieve valve to the safety calculation. I can take a general MTTFd value but then I will not have a DC value. Maybe there is a standard I need to follow, it has been a while since I did work with the safety standards so there is a big change I am missing some thing. Could someone please tell me how to approach this?

I cannot comment on your safety regulation requirements, (whether such a mechanical valve meets particular code) but TP valves are in such common usage, that I would be surprised if they did not.  Rather than having your PLC open the valve on over-pressure, I do suggest that you have the PLC controlled electric safety valve holding it closed. Then in case of power failure or failure of the valve it will fail to its default value - open.

Rich, thank you yes using a normally open valve is the best way to go here. However if I  compare the valve with an electrical relay. If the electric coil of the relay is activated a metal part of the relay moves and makes contact. This way a electrical current can flow from A to B. You can buy relays with mechanical (not electrical) connected contacts e.g. contact C and D. The PLC reads a signal from D it be can used to see / test if the relay fails. The better you can test the higher your DC value. you need a DC value to get to performance level D. I need a rationale for no or less to tests
